# IE8 Loading and Moving Ads with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I load my AdSense ads at the top of my web page at http://www.RomanceStuck.com. I then use the following Javascript code to move those ads to where I want them to appear on the page:

```
  <!-- POSITION AD - START -->
    <div id="ad_nav_1_position">
    </div>
    <script>
      if (document.getElementById('ad_nav_1') != null)
      {
        document.getElementById('ad_nav_1_position').appendChild(document.getElementById('ad_nav_1'));
      }
    </script>
  <!-- POSITION AD - END -->
```

This seems to work for most browsers but I just realized it is not working in IE8. IE8 loads the ads at the top of the page but it never moves the ads. Can someone tell me how I can get this to work?

Comment: All of a sudden, it looks like the ads are displaying where I want them but I didn't change anything Maybe they had been cached or something. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Put your javascript inside Jquery methods.

```
$(document).ready() or $(window).load().
```

Or use simple JS .onload method as follows.

```
window.onload=function(){
    Your-code-here....
};
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using jQuery?

Comment: Of course, you can do the same thing with simple js method window.onload. Check out the updated answer.